# Adding listeners to spring batch deciders

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Hey I am having a little trouble with my spring batch application context. I need my decider to be able to look at the jobParameters that are passed through the job launcher. For a normal tasklet I would use the @beforeStep on a method and get the information through that, I would also use a listener so that the tasklet can reach that @beforeStep like this :

```
    <batch:step id="verifyDatabase" next="full.incremental.decision">
        <batch:tasklet ref="verifyDatabaseTasklet" />
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="verifyDatabaseTasklet" />
            <batch:listener ref="PromotionListener" />
        </batch:listeners>
    </batch:step>
```

however, I want to be able to do the same thing with a decision. Something like this:

```
    <batch:decision id="full.incremental.decision" decider="fullIncrementalDecider">
        <batch:next on="COMPLETED" to="incrementalUpdate" />
        <batch:next on="FAILED" to="fullUpdate" />
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="full.incremental.decision" />
        </batch:listeners>
    </batch:decision>
```

When I do that I get this error

```
 cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with 
 element 'batch:listeners'. One of '{"http://
 www.springframework.org/schema/batch":next, "http://
 www.springframework.org/schema/batch":stop, "http://
 www.springframework.org/schema/batch":end, "http://
 www.springframework.org/schema/batch":fail}' is expected.
```

I know that this probably means listeners are not allowed in the decisions? Is that correct? Is there anyway I can reach my jobParameters in my JobExecutionDecider?

Thanks a bunch

Comment: OH WOW! Really dumb moment. the decide method in the JobExecutionDecider takes the Job and Step Executions as parameters. Sorry everyone.